# Excel code in separate file

Tags: excel, vba, external

I have been programming in MS Access for many years and best practice is to keep the code in one file and the data in another. 
I have recently been asked to carry out some work on an Excel file.  It will arrive each day from an external party and then need reformatting before being uploaded into another 3rd party application. i.e.

1. Move data in column G to column H
2. Remove special characters from all data('"';)
3. Check column A for a space in the postcode
4. Plus a few more data validation checks.

So, my questions is where should the code go.

Do I create the code in a blank spreadsheet and then cut and paste the data into it or is there a way in Excel to write code external to the spreadsheet and then run it? i.e. separate code from data

Thanks

Comment: You can put code in your personal workbook. If you search stackoverflow there are lots of examples. It is a normally invisible workbook that exists where you can store code. There also other ways such as add-ins, imports from files placed in your open workbook event......See here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566?CorrelationId=c0deff56-a956-4e6d-82dc-afc2f444e0a7&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102174076

Comment: Create an Excel add-in (.xlam) with your code and load it to the workbook you need to format.

Comment: Either of the previous comments, or you can put it in a normal Excel file.  I can't think of any alterations you'd need to make to the code for each case.  You'll just need to reference the Excel file you're sent and use that throughout the code - not explicitly referencing the correct workbook & worksheet will mean the code uses the active book & sheet. `ThisWorkbook` will reference the personal workbook or add-in.

Comment: All, thanks for your great help in starting me off in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is through the use of VB.net Excel addin.  Although your application files would be attached to excel, they would be maintained is separate files.  But, have you thought of doing the work with formulas?  It looks to me like the requirements listed can be done with them.  You could import the source into one sheet and reference/validate on another one with formulas.